# 3D scatter plot combined with user-defined adjustable planes

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, interactive

I am trying to find some service/application/web-app or otherwise that allows for the following functionality:

1. Plot points in 3d space.
2. Insert plane in 3d space wherever I like. As in it must not be the case that the only plane that can be inserted must be a regression plane that has been fit to the data. I should be able to insert the plane where ever I want, independent of the data points I have plotted.
3. This 3d space should be interactive (rotatable and zoomable).
4. I should be able to adjust the tilt of the plane in any direction.
5. I should be able to see the residuals between the points and the plane.
6. These residuals should be adjusting in real-time based on me interactively tilting the plane.

Points 1-3 are easily met with Geogebra (and I'm sure other applications). 4-6 is what I am struggling to find. It seems like perhaps mathematica may offer this functionality but I'm not sure.

If this doesn't exist to your knowledge, do you know if there is some application I can use to create this?

Comment: *Mathematica* will do all 6 items.  Once you're a bit familiar with *Mathematica*, please share the code you've developed if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply. I cannot see greyed out checkmark next to your answer which I am to click in order to accept your answer. Has the way to accept an answer changed? (Also, I am new to this place).

Comment: That's because I just gave a comment and not answer.  You should look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour.  Also, your question could use a bit more focus.  Unless there is a specific question about where you're having issues with *Mathematica* code for which you need help, your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

A naive approach might be something like the following:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {100, 3}];
Manipulate[
  Show[
    ListPointPlot3D[
      pts,
      Axes -> None,
      BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
      PlotRange -> zoom {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}
    ],
    Graphics3D[{
      Blue,
      Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 10 {Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]], Tan[\[Phi]]}}],
      Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, 10 {Sin[\[Theta] + 90 Degree], Cos[\[Theta] + 90 Degree], 0}}],
      Opacity[0.2],
      InfinitePlane[
        {0, 0, 0}, 
        {
          {Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]], Tan[\[Phi]]}, 
          {Sin[\[Theta] + 90 Degree], Cos[\[Theta] + 90 Degree], 0}}],
        }
      ]
    ],
  {{\[Theta], 0}, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
  {{\[Phi], 0}, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2},
  {{zoom, 1}, 0.1, 10}
]
```

[image: Animated version of the object OP requested.z]

Of course, there are an infinite number of adjustments that can be made. I'm not familiar with Geogebra, but Mathematica (or the Wolfram Language, I guess) is a full-fledged programming language. This means you can do **anything** you want, provided you have sufficient time and talent.

Mathematica also offers a built in way to rotate the plot by clicking-and-dragging it, but you could also programmatically control that with `ViewPoint` and other, similar options.